# How can I request a transfer to my manager?

Tags: internal-transfer

I'm a software professional working for a big MNC in India.This MNC has many offices all over the world.I have recently completed one year at my workplace. At the time of joining,I was informed by the recruiting team that I'll be transferred back to my hometown after a year if I accepted working in other location(As the requirement was at a different location from my homwetown). At first I was reluctant to accept this ,but after speaking to the senior HR & some other guys from the management, I accepted relocating to this new place. Now that I have completed a year from the 'Date of my Joining' , How can I request a transfer to my manager? 
                Moreover, I'm not comfortable living away from my family. Last one year has been the toughest year in my life so far. I feel that i'm just wasting my precious time by working here. I know , I can work far better than my current self if I work from my hometown. Since i'm staying away from home, my efficiency at work is cut to half. As I have done with the time given to me, How can I say the same to my manager & request for a transfer?

Comment: What is it about this workplace and/or your manager that makes you feel reluctant to ask for something that was already promised?

Comment: Why would your efficiency be cut in half by not being in your hometown? Most managers would be reluctant to accept a transfer of a less productive employee, so it is important to do good work no matter where you are located.

Answer (score 4):

**Question:** "How can I request a transfer?"
**Answer:** "Request a transfer."

I'm going to be a bit blunt now. Why is it so difficult to speak up and ask for what you were told would be available to you? *Do it.* What can happen? You get the transfer... or you don't. Until you request it, you'll never know for sure.